# PHPUnit throws a PHPUnit_Framework_Exception with no error message

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm working on some new functionality for a package I work with, but PHPUnit is throwing an exception without any error message.

Code:

```
use Bootstrapper\Modal;

class ModalTest extends BootstrapperWrapper
{ 

    public function testCanOpenModel() {
        $modal = Modal::create();
        $matcher = array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'attributes' => array(
        'class' => 'modal'
        ),
        );
        $this->assertHTML($matcher, $modal);
    }

}
```

AssertHTML is just a wrapper around assertTag which we use so we can have a helpful error message.

```
class Modal {

    protected static $modal = null;

    protected $attributes;

    protected $header;

    protected $body;

    protected $footer;

    public static function create($attributes = null, $header = null, $body = null, $footer = null) {
        static::$modal = new static($attributes, $header, $body, $footer);
    }

    public function __construct($attributes, $header, $body, $footer) {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
        $this->header = $header;
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->footer = $footer;
    }


    public function render() {
        $this->attributes = Helpers::add_class($this->attributes, 'modal');

        $string = "<div" . Helpers::getContainer('html')->attributes($this->$attributes) . ">";

    return $string . "</div>";
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->render();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->$attributes = Helpers::add_class($attributes, 'modal');

$string = "<div" . Helpers::getContainer('html')->attributes($this->$attributes) . ">";
```

Change `$this->$attributes` to `$this->attributes` and `$attributes` to `$this->attributes`.

It is hard to say if this causes your problems, but give it a try.

Comment: Whoops, I am a dumb.

Sadly didn't fix it though :(

Comment: Did you change line `$string = "<div" . Helpers::getContainer('html')->attributes($this->$attributes) . ">";` too?

Comment: It turns out I'm still a dumb. Even with that, it doesn't work. Though surely I'd get an actual error message even with that?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. The create method didn't return anything (thus gaving me null) which makes PHPunit framework error out. Why it doesn't give an error message is anyone's guess.